# Check if a binary tree is balanced (Big-O)

Tags: binary-tree, big-o

Check if a binary tree is balanced.

The source code on the CTCI 5th:

```
public class QuestionBrute {

public static int getHeight(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return Math.max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right)) + 1;
}

public static boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return true;
    }
    int heightDiff = getHeight(root.left) - getHeight(root.right);
    if (Math.abs(heightDiff) > 1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create balanced tree
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    TreeNode root = TreeNode.createMinimalBST(array);
    System.out.println("Root? " + root.data);
    System.out.println("Is balanced? " + isBalanced(root));

    // Could be balanced, actually, but it's very unlikely...
    TreeNode unbalanced = new TreeNode(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        unbalanced.insertInOrder(AssortedMethods.randomIntInRange(0, 100));
    }
    System.out.println("Root? " + unbalanced.data);
    System.out.println("Is balanced? " + isBalanced(unbalanced));
}
}
```

As the algorithm has to check the height of every node, and we don't save the height in each recursion, the running time should be O(N^2).

Comment: You are not maintaining a reference to Height, which means you have to calculate it which adds another degree of complexity.

You have to calculate height which takes O(N), and you have to do it as a traversal which also takes O(N), resulting in O(N^2)

Comment: Though it's a recursion, I think all I have to do is calculate the height of each node. So that should be O(N).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all let's fix a bit your code. Your function to check if the root is balanced will not work simply because a binary tree is balanced if:

```
maxHeight(root) - minHeight(root) <= 1
```

I quote Wikipedia: "A balanced binary tree is commonly defined as a binary tree in which the depth of the two subtrees of every node differ by 1 or less"

Your algorithm will give the wrong answer for this tree:

[image: A simple binary tree of size 9 and height 3, with a root node whose value is 2. The above tree is unbalanced and not sorted.]

When you call `getHeight(Node7)` it will return 3, and when you call `getHeight(Node5)` it will return 3 as well and since `(0>1) == false` you will return `true` :(

To fix this all you have to do is to implement the `int MinHeight(TreeNode node)` the same way you did `getHeight()` but with `Math.min()`

Now to your answer. In terms of runtime complexity whenever you call the `getHeight()` function from the root you are doing a [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and since you have to visit all the nodes to find the height of the tree this algorithm will be O(N). Now it is true you execute this algorithm twice, when you call `maxHeight(root)` and `minHeight(root)` but since they are both O(N) (given that they do exactly what `getHeight()` does) the overall complexity will have C*N as an upper limit for some constant C and all N bigger than some N knot i.e. O(N) where N is the number of nodes of your tree ;)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for fixing the bug. Calculate MaxHeight() and MinHeight() is also the original way in CTCI 4th edition. While in the 5th edition, they provide getHeight() function and says the time is O(N^2), so it's confusing.

Comment: can you share the 5th edition? I'd like to take a look at it. if the function is defined as you posted it that function will run in O(n) and you will not able to find whether a tree is balanced or not with it.

Comment: Sure, I post it on a new comment.

Comment: that explains it… you left out the key part of the algorithm and you should edit your question then for it to make sense. Also you shouldn't have posted the algorithm as an answer. In your question add the `isBalanced()` algorithm as they show it in the article. it is not `else return true` ;). When you do that I will explain why it's O(N^2)

Comment: I got it. In isBalanced(), the algorithm check every node, so each node could be visited several times. And the recursion gives O(N^2).

Comment: It is exactly O(N^2) because this sum: 1+2+3+4+…+n expands to `n*(n+1)/2` which is O(N^2). From `isBalanced()` you can figure out if you make a table how you will indeed call the recursion that many times ;)